# Why do I not get a error when addressing an element outside the range of an array in C++ VS 2019

Tags: c++, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I have got a strange behaviour in my C++ code in VS19. I have the following code:

```cpp
bool tru;
int ax[3] = { 1,2,3 };
int val = ax[5];
tru = (ax[5] == 1);
```

When I run this I get:

[image]

I would expect to get an error in line 3 but I get `a[5] = 0xcccccccc`. In this case tru = false would be correct. I have been using Qt Creator before which would crash in this case.

**Can someone explain this behavior of Vs2019 to me?**

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. It might crash, it might not, either way it is incorrect and the programmer is responsible to make sure that doesn't happen. 0xCC is one of the special values the debug heap will set memory to. https://stackoverflow.com/a/370362/920069

Comment: This is one example of `C makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot; C++ makes it harder, but when you do it blows your whole leg off"` . You have *undefined behavior* and anything can happen.

Comment: *I would expect to get an error* -- What kind of error were you expecting?  A crash?  A popup window saying you did something wrong?  Regardless, all of that requires C++ to check array boundaries, and C++ does no checking of such.

Comment: *I have been using Qt Creator before which would crash in this case.* -- In C++, there is a concept called *undefined behavior*.  There is nothing "strange" about what you are seeing -- when you write code that accesses an element outside the bounds of an array, access an uninitialized pointer, or do a whole host of other things that are too many to name, the behavior of the program becomes undefined.  You were mistaken to think that C++ checks for things like this -- it doesn't.  That's where you must be aware of this, and gain the experience of identifying these issues in your code.